# How to specify the domain for a named route in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, routes, subdomain

I am trying to figure out an issue related to subdomains for a Laravel application. I have two domains, `site.com` and `feature.site.com`, both pointed to my Laravel application. In my routes folder, I have separated out the routes to each domain (web.php and features.php), wrapped them correctly using `Route::domain`, and the function of visiting each site and getting the desired results works fine.

Where I am having an issue is with named routes. There are links on the `feature.site.com` domain that link to pages that should only be accessible on the `site.com` domain. For instance, I have a route that links to the user profile, with the name of the route being `profile`. When I add a link to this route like so, `{{ route('profile') }}`, the route generated is still on the `feature.site.com` domain even though the named route is not defined in that domain group, and I want to direct the user back to the `site.com` domain for this.

How would I link back to the `site.com` domain from `feature.site.com` with named routes?

Answer (score 0):

**web.php**

```
Route::domain('site.com')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/profile', 'ProfileController@profile')->name('profile');
});
```

**features.php**

```
Route::domain('feature.site.com')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/show-named-route', function () {
        dd(route('profile'));
    });
});
```

When I go to **feature.site.com/show-named-route** path the result will be `Protocol://site.com/profile`
I've tested in **Laravel 7**

Comment: Might be my version - I'm on 6.18. Cause it's definitely not working for me